# A way to calculate orbital energy of an electron

Tags: electronic-configuration, spectrophotometry

Maybe this is just not included in my course, but I still wonder how to calculate the binding energy of an electron .at a certain electron orbital.

Intuitively,The ionization energy of an element should vary depending on which orbital the valence electron is in.

PS: I only know how to calculate ionization energy using principle level.

Comment: I think we'd need to know what course you're taking. This can be determined from quantum mechanics, but in general the numbers are tabulated because the equations get extremely complicated.

Comment: High school general Chem

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the ionization energy of an electron depends on the orbital. **There is no easy formula,** because the electrons in atoms are governed by quantum mechanics and for multi-electron atoms, the equations are un-solvable algebraically.

That said, there are some reasonable tabulations, which have been verified by calculations and by spectroscopy, e.g., http://www.colby.edu/chemistry/PChem/notes/AOIE.pdf (from a quick Google search).

Both ultraviolet photoelectron spectroscopy and x-ray photoelectron spectroscopy can be used to eject electrons from various materials, and you can thus identify elemental composition (and other properties) from the known orbital energy levels

Comment: What is name of the name of the equation and why proposed it?

Comment: If you'd like to read more about [quantum mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics) you would want to read about the Schrödinger model of the hydrogen atom. But it helps to have some familiarity with differential equations first.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across this question ... a little late....

A common approximation in XPS to solve this question is Koopmans theorem (frozen-orbital approximation). If the remaining (those were not photo-electron was removed) orbitals of the exited atom after photo-ionisation do not change between the initial and final state (no relaxation)  the experimental binding energies are than taken to be equal to the respective negative Hartree-Fock/KS orbital energy.
A good way to start reading is this Book:
[Book](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540418023)
See also:
[Link](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/sia.6319)
[Link2](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/2015/CP/C4CP05434B#!divAbstract)